# 写真共有サービスのような大量の画像を扱うサーバー構成について

Tags: amazon-s3

現在、インスタグラムのような写真共有アプリを作っています。
サーバーはConoHaを利用しています。

ConoHaのVPSではディスク容量が最大でも500GBまでしか増やせないのですが、仮に500GB近くまで容量がいった時、その場合はどのように対応するのが適切なのでしょうか？

もう一つVPSを増やすみたいなやり方なのか、それとも最初からVPSのディスクは利用せず、写真などの保存はConoHaでしたら「オブジェクトストレージ」やAWSの「S3」などを利用したほうが良いのでしょうか？
調べたところ「オブジェクトストレージ」などは速度が遅いというので、このようなケースをご存知の方がいましたら、ぜひ色々なアドバイスをいただきたいです。

現在は「APPサーバー」→「DBサーバー」という構成になっています。

サーバー構築は未経験でして周りにも詳しい人がいないため、ぜひご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: 詳しくご説明していただきましてありがとうございます。
S3ではそこまで速度は気になるほどではないんですね。
お話伺ってますとS3は便利そうだなと思いますが、やはり金銭的にちょっと迷ってしまいます。
ConoHaですと通信料含めてすべて定額制なので、未経験の自分が最初に手を付けるにはちょうどいいのかなとも思っています。

一度ConoHaのオブジェクトストレージを使ってみてテストしてみようと思います。

経験者の貴重な知識とアドバイスは大変勉強になりました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

クラウド上に構築する方法で手軽なものは、記載されている通りS3などを利用する方法です。

速度には確かに制限がありますが、S3の東京リージョン・標準ストレージでこれまで数年日本市場向けに動画のストリーム配信を行ってきた限りでは、特に遅いと感じることはありませんでした。経験上、クライアント側が太い回線であれば10Mbps程度はでます。（東京であればレイテンシも非常に小さいです）

ConoHaのオブジェクトストレージは利用したことがないのですが、S3はnekoさんのような用途で利用できる便利な機能がたくさんあります。オブジェクトへのアクセス権限設定はもちろん、例えば、Pre-Signed URLといって、期限付きのワンタイムのURLを発行することなどもできます。なにより「ストレージのスケールについて悩む必要がなくなる」「写真の読込に関するトラフィック負荷をすべてS3が負ってくれる」という点が非常にありがたいです。

さらにパフォーマンスについて要求の高い環境では、S3と組み合わせてCloudFrontなどのCDNにキャッシュさせる方法もあります。追加費用がかかりますが、読込のパフォーマンスが向上します。

もう1つの手軽は方法としては、Elastic File Systemを利用する方法もあります。
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/efs/

こちらはVPSではなくEC2のインスタンスと組み合わせる前提のサービスですが、S3などの外部ストレージとしてではなくインスタンスに直接接続されたものとして、自動拡張されるストレージが利用できるため、シーンによってはS3よりももっと手軽かもしれません。（ただし、こちらは東京リージョンがまだないのと、料金もS3より割高です）